# Show that f '(a) exists for all a if f is linear

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^m$ is linear, prove that $f'(a)$ exists for all $a$ in $\mathbb R$, with $dfa = f$

Comment: what is Rm and what is dfa?

Comment: i suggested an edit didn't you like it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Derivative is an approximation with a linear function this one should be clear.
As 
$$f(x+h)=f(x) + f(h) = f(x)+ f\cdot h $$ this one is true.

Comment: Thanks so much, to be honest I had that but its so simple that I couldn't believe it to be true.

Comment: i am glad when i can help, if there is any question tell it :)